# Can I somehow suppress empty window with ssh.exe when using remote development extension?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-remote

I am using VSCode 1.35.0 with recently added Remote Development extension and when I try to connect to ssh via jump host everything works fine as expected but empty ssh.exe terminal appears.

[image]

```
Version: 1.35.0 (system setup)
Commit: 553cfb2c2205db5f15f3ee8395bbd5cf066d357d
Date: 2019-06-04T01:17:12.481Z
Electron: 3.1.8
Chrome: 66.0.3359.181
Node.js: 10.2.0
V8: 6.6.346.32
OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.17134
```

**Can this be suppressed?**

Comment: Possibly. How does the program get instantiated? I am using `ssh.exe` with Git to auth into AWS, and the terminal does not pop up in that case.

Comment: I use full path to ssh.exe after fixing the error in 1903 https://serverfault.com/questions/956613/windows-10-ssh-proxycommand-posix-spawn-no-such-file-or-directory

Comment: To clarify, did any answers in that link resolve it?

Comment: Not this specific issue but I believe this is the reason for that windows and that is how it is being invoked.

Comment: Is there anywhere you can specify the command line? For example in Git, I use `set GIT_SSH_COMMAND=ssh -i C:\path\to\id_rsa` - I wonder if there is a "quiet" switch you can use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue seems to be fixed in `vscode 1.36.x`

For more info see this issue: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues/230